# Google Play Store won't download app

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services, download-manager

Play Store downloads successfully first chosen app, but it get stuck on downloading the second one. There is no error message. Only activity I see is notification of content waiting to be downloaded. Solution is to reboot the phone.

Here is a screenshot that shows kind of notification I am writing about, since I am unable to provide an actual one. No error messages, just a continuous progress bar:

[image: screenshot]

I tried clearing cache, then all data and then data in Google Play Services app, but it didn't help. The phone is Oukitel U11 Plus, using Android 8.

I have visited [wiki page of google-play-store tag](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info) and didn't found any reasonable advice in regard of this situation.

---

On the side note, one other frustrating thing is happening, too. When searching in Chrome it redirects to local .rs domain, but it then prints out `err_tunnel_connection_failed`. I got around it buy using *no redirect* link to force it to go main .com domain.

Comment: Have you already checked with our [google-play-store tag-wiki](/tags/google-play-store/info)? It lists many issues around playstore and links to solutions. Without an explicit error message it's hard to help in another way.

Comment: @Izzy I didn't, thank you for providing me that! How to get an explicit error message on this kind of problem?

Comment: No error message shown? Nothing like "coulnd not be downloaded due to an error (498)"? Just sticking and doing nothing? Well, that would be a hint to include with your question, too. Also see these posts [on stalled](/search?q=[google-play-store]+stalled) or [on stuck](/search?q=[google-play-store]+stuck) downloads with Playstore then.

Comment: @Izzy Nothing, just an infinite downloading progress bar as a notification.

Comment: Thanks, that update helped. So it's the "stalled or stuck" categorie, but rather the download not even starting ("knight-rider style" progress bar if I get that right). Maybe one of the search results I've linked to in my previous comment provides some help/ideas? Have you checked?

Comment: @Izzy I've checked your link, but have found no help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: As a work-around until your issue is solved, you could use [Yalp Store](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.github.yeriomin.yalpstore) or [Aurora Store](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.dragons.aurora).

Comment: See if this works: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/197291/209414

Answer (score 0):

Do you have background data restricted? If not then try clearing cache & data of the following Apps:

Download Manager,
Google Account Manager,
Google Services Framework

Then reboot & open play store it will ask you to log in with your Google Account, after logging in try installing something it should be working now.

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is related to the carrier (and/or 4G)? At the moment I can't test if switching to 3G helps.

Answer (score 0):

If we have set the download by WiFi only could be the reason. Change to Mobile data as well or try connecting to WiFi