# Can't download offline packages in Google translate

Tags: 7.1-nougat

I have the same problem as this guy [How to fix the problem of offline packages not downloading in Google Translate?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/197207/how-to-fix-the-problem-of-offline-packages-not-downloading-in-google-translate#)
But the answer there, that is clearing data of the download manager didn't work for me.
I have tried some other things as the op from that post like reinstalling the app and I checked that I granted it all the permissions.

I run at Android 7.1.1 on Nokia 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the app and change your downloading preferences to both mobile data and WiFi. It will still download on WiFi if you are connected, but this change will get it out of that holding pattern. Make sure to restart the download once you make the change.